# How to remove root from a folder?

Tags: jquery, html, apache, ubuntu, root

I was trying to set up my own web site on a small Ubuntu Server machine. All goes well, until I try to install the `jquery-filemanager`, and it creates an error because it cannot write to the directory: `/var/www/html`. I am using `apache2`, and I noticed that it requires `root/sudo` every time I try to delete/copy/move a file. I am pretty sure that this is what is causing this problem.

Is there a way to stop `root` from owning this directory, or are there any better websites that I could use?

Thanks.

EDIT: I did an "ls -la" on the directory "/var/www/html".

```
cameron@ubuntuserver:/var/www/html$ ls -la
```

total 72
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Apr 14 16:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 14 06:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  203 Apr 13 19:25 AdminDevel.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7372 Apr 13 19:49 contact.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 13 16:44 css
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Apr 14 16:53 filemanager
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Apr 13 16:54 FOLDERS
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 13 16:44 fonts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6056 Apr 13 19:33 games.html
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul  5  2012 halftone-files
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   73 Mar  4 13:25 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Apr 13 18:06 img
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7769 Apr 14 15:00 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Apr 13 16:44 js
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 13 16:44 less
cameron@ubuntuserver:/var/www/html$

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a `ls -la` so we can see what the owner is and the permissions?

Anyway the permissions should be www-data if you are using apache. You can do this by doing `sudo chown -R www:data-www:data /var/www/html`

Read about `chown` and `chmod`.